# Need to know a graphics enabled laptop that installs ubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nomodeset

Does anyone know a laptop with a decent Nvidia or AMD graphics card that installs Ubuntu out of the box, or with minimal tweaking?
I am going nuts with my new Lenovo E485 with Ryzen + AMD graphics.  It needs a nomodeset instruction ( apparently ) and all attempts to add this after quiet splash then control x are failing just get that same black screen. Also it will NOT go into setup with F1 on  startup.  I have recently purchased so I think I will be able to return.

Comment: You can buy Dell laptops with Ubuntu preinstalled.

Comment: And it's F2, not F1.

Comment: thanks.  after several hours trying several recommendations and no luck I have returned the laptop.  Do not buy a new Lenovo until the factory address this problem. Dell seem to be more supportive, may look at them.